# PLS-00103 error when compile a Package

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

When I try to compile this package, I get the error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “BEGIN” when expecting one of the following: end function pragma procedure subtype type       current cursor delete    exists prior

Can anyone help me, please?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PCK_TB_ESTADO
IS
  PROCEDURE PRC_INSERE
  (P_NM_REDE_FUNCIONARIO IN TB_FUNCIONARIO.NM_REDE_FUNCIONARIO%TYPE,
  P_DS_ESTADO IN TB_ESTADO.DS_ESTADO%TYPE,
  P_ID_UF IN TB_ESTADO.ID_UF%TYPE,
  P_MENS OUT VARCHAR2)
  BEGIN
    CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ESTADO
      MINVALUE 1
      MAXVALUE 99
      START WITH 1
      INCREMENT BY 1;
    INSERT INTO TB_ESTADO
    VALUES (SEQ_ESTADO.NEXTVAL,P_DS_ESTADO,P_ID_UF,SYSDATE,P_NM_REDE_FUNCIONARIO);
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        P_MENS := 'Você tentou executar um comando INSERT ou UPDATE que criou um valor duplicado em um campo restrito por um index único.';
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        P_MENS := 'Erro.';
  END;
END PCK_TB_ESTADO;
```

Comment: You're missing `IS` keyword before `BEGIN`

Comment: I already tried with IS keyword and I got the same error.

Comment: I'm sure you already created the package spec. And this being Package Body, you need to write `BODY` in `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PCK_TB_ESTADO`. Also, you can't directly create Sequence inside the procedure, that being a DDL command.

Comment: No. This is my package spec, the package body is another code that I already has created but not compiled yet.

Comment: If this is your package spec, then you don't need to write the code for procedure here! That's what goes in `PACKAGE BODY`. Spec just contains the signature of the procedures/functions

Comment: You're right! I didn't know that. Appreciate so much your help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the Issues:

1. A Package Specification only contains the signature of the procedures/functions it is supposed to contain. The code for the procs/functions goes into the Package Body
2. You cannot have a DDL statement directly inside your Procedure. You can however execute DDLs using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
3. The Procedure definition in the Package Body should have `IS/AS` keyword before `BEGIN`